# .NET 6 LTS - VS17/22, build output multiple files, not a single executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build

Despite searching (though I'm not great at searching SO) I cannot find anything specific to the problem I'm having

Using VS2022, I fire up and create a completely blank new project as a Windows Forms App targeting .NET 6 (not "framework", or "core", just flat .NET6)

VS finishes loading, I click "build" and when looking in the directory it's creating not only the project .exe but also a .dll of the same name, couple .jsons (which it won't run without) and a debug symbols file (not necessary to run)

Am I doing something ridiculously stupid here?- Used to be I click 'build', go fetch JUST the .exe and send it to a friend, they can run the .EXE without needing the .DLL and .JSON files to be distributed with it

I know I'm not going through the steps for a single-file deployment, that's different from what I'm getting at.  I've always only had the single built .EXE be required to run the app (obviously with the requisite framework being installed on the target machine)

I've tried modifying the .csproj file (as below) to include lines for single-file output but that causes VS to create multiple folders with dozens or hundreds of files and no executable in sight (only a .dll of the project's supposed .exe name)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm at a complete loss and more than not feeling like an idiot anymore, I'd really like to get back to only having to grab just the single .exe when sending a simple winforms project to a friend

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, or some massive change to C#/.NET/Whatever that needs to be explained, I'd be sincerely appreciative

Comment: I tried .net 3.1, .net 5.0, both output multiple files after building the project.

Answer (score -1):

According to [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#produce-a-cross-platform-binary):

> Apps published as framework-dependent are cross-platform and don't
> include the .NET runtime. The user of your app is required to install
> the .NET runtime.
>
> Publishing an app as framework-dependent produces a cross-platform
> binary as a dll file, and a platform-specific executable that targets
> your current platform. The dll is cross-platform while the executable
> isn't.  For example, if you publish an app named word_reader and target Windows, a word_reader.exe executable is created along with word_reader.dll
> ...
>
> The cross-platform binary of your app can be run with the dotnet
> <filename.dll> command, and can be run on any platform.

Comment: That's related to my question, but not what I was getting at.. The cross-platform is irrelevant as the problem I was getting at was that the .exe produced isn't runnable without having the .json files present in the same directory.. It USED to be that you could run the .exe alone, in a separate folder, without any accompanying files as long as the framework was installed..  I'm building for Windows, *with* framework installed, but a simple winforms app *used to* run with only the .exe, nothing else had to be copied/distributed as long as the framework was installed

Comment: @MisterNad: _Used to be I click 'build', go fetch JUST the .exe and send it to a friend, they can run the .EXE without needing the .DLL and .JSON files to be distributed with it. It's not clear what you're talking about. Which product are you talking about?  _.NET Framework (1.1, 2.0, ...4.8)_, _.NET Core (1.1, 2.0, ...3.1))_, _.NET (5, 6, 7, 8)_? These are all different products, although Microsoft has stated: _.NET 5 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1_. See the following:  [What's new in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5).